# Swift inheritance function return type can't be sub-type

Tags: swift, inheritance, swiftui, subclass, return-type

Consider the following code:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
protocol P {
    var a: A {get}
}
class P1: P {
    let a: A = B() // No problem
}
class P2: P {
    let a: B = B() // Can't compile!!
}
```

Since `B` is a sub class of `A`, why can't we make `B` as return type of `var a` ?

Comment: I believe it is because your protocol has a var or type A and not B, and B is a subclass of A. So, P2 has no idea what type is B.

Comment: Dear PO, everything is clear now about your question ?

Comment: I think it is the constraint of Swift. In other language like Scala, Java and Kotlin, the declaration in `P2` is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that because `P` protocol specifically asks the conforming class to have a property of type `A`.

You can always use `associatedtype` and generics in your protocol:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
protocol P {
    associatedtype T: A
    var a: T { get }
}
class P1: P {
    let a: A = B()
}
class P2: P {
    let a: B = B()
}
```

Keep in mind though, that if you do that you cannot use `P` protocol as a type directly but only with generics:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
protocol P {
    var a: A {get}
}

class P1: P {
    let a: A = B() // No problem
}

class P1x: P {
    let a = A() // No problem
 
}

class P1y: P {
    var a = A()
    
    let b: B = B() // No problem
}
```

Now your confused point :

```
class P2: P {
    let a: B = B() // Can't compile!
}
```

Because **a belongs to type A not B as declared in protocol B !**